# Django - AttributeError at / 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, get, attributeerror

I am getting an attribute error at:

```
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\Desktop\django-basics\env\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py, line 26, in process_response
```

**This is the said location (the process_response function):**

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    # Don't set it if it's already in the response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
        return response
```

**My views file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Student
def studentlist(request):
    get_students = Student.objects.all()

    data = {
        'get_students' : get_students
    }
    return render(request, 'studentlist.html', data)
```

**My templates file studentlist.html:**

```
{% load static %}
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
<title>Student List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-5">Student List</h2>
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Roll No.</th>
        <th scope="col">Photo</th>
        <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Gender</th>
        <th scope="col">Course</th>
        <th scope="col">Grade in course</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for student in get_students %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ student.roll_no }}</td>
        <td>
          <img src="{{ student.photo.url }}" width="40" height="40"/>
        </td>
        <td>{{ student.full_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.course }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.grade }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.gender }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I need to add more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a trailing comma after the `return ...` statement?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no commas after that sir

Comment: can you put your template file as well

Comment: @raviadhikari yes

Comment: Are you sure that 1) That is the view run in the request you get an error on? 2) You don't have any other variable / function named `render`? Please share the _full_ error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

if someone has the same issue, the answer from Willem van Onsem was the one that fixed my issue, I had a coma at the end.